# convert number to string

Tags: c#, string

I have:

```
int i=8;
i.ToString();
```

if i do this i get "8"
i want "08"

is possible setting an option in tostring parameter ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
?8.ToString("00")
"08"
?8.ToString("000")
"008"
?128.ToString("000")
"128"
?128.ToString("000.00")
"128,00"
?128.ToString("0000.##")
"0128"
```

Also you can use the [string.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) methods (like `String.Format("{0,10:G}: {0,10:X}", value)`) or display your number in [Standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) or [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Other useful examples:

```
?5/3
1.6666666666666667
?String.Format("{0:0.00}", 5/3)
"1,67"
?System.Math.Round(5/3, 2)
1.67
?(5.0 / 3).ToString("0.00")
"1,67"
?(5 / 3).ToString("0.00")
"1,00"
?(5.0 / 3).ToString("E") //Exponential
"1,666667E+000"
?(5.0 / 3).ToString("F") //Fixed-point
"1,67"
?(5.0 / 3).ToString("N") //Number
"1,67"
?(5.0 / 3).ToString("C") //Currency
"1,67 €"
?(5.0 / 3).ToString("G") //General
"1,66666666666667"
?(5.0 / 3).ToString("R") //Round-trip
"1,6666666666666667"
?(5.0 / 3).ToString("this is it .")
"this is it 2"
?(5.0 / 3).ToString("this is it .0")
"this is it 1,7"
?(5.0 / 3).ToString("this is it .0##")
"this is it 1,667"
?(5.0 / 3).ToString("this is it #####")
"this is it 2"
?(5.0 / 3).ToString("this is it .###")
"this is it 1,667"
```

Comment: It took me a while to recall that `?` is a BASIC short cut to print a value to the console.

Comment: '?' is the symbol used in the Immediate Window of Visual Studio for obtain variable values :)

Comment: It may be obvious but serhio has a set up for "," to be the decimal and Euro for currency so 1,667 = 1.667 for others...for those not quite awake yet :)

Comment: @Mark: Yes. I am *€uropean*! With meters, Euros, Kilograms and Celsius degrees :)

Answer (score 4):

```
i.ToString("D2")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the .ToString() parameter but here is another option:

```
int i = 8;
i.ToString.PadLeft(2, (char)"0")
```